# Error Installing Lion MAC OS on my Mac/book Pro Early 2011

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootable-disk

**Background:** I purchased an old Mac Book Pro early 2011, It came with High sierra installed. Unfortunately I leave the mac on without the power cable, the mac entered into hibernation mode and eventually the battery ran out. When I tried to turn the mac on, the OS did not start.

**The problem:** My Mac Book does not boot, not even on safe mode, I tried to Re install the entire OS but the installation never finish, just when the installation is about the 90% the mac reboots.

**Things I tried:**

1. Using recovery mode to install the OS: I can access to the recovery mode, even the disk utility, but the mac reboots when the installation is about to finish.
2. Used internet recovery, same happen.
3. Reseting the NvRam and SMC did not solve the problem.
4. Tried with the Bootable USB, did not solve the problem.
5. I also tried installing Ubuntu with a bootable USb but never started, happened the same, the OS did not started and the mac rebooted.

In summary all the solutions always take me to the same place, when the installation is about to finish, the mac reboots and the installation never fully completed.

I noticed there are a lot of errors in the console log of the installation:
[image]

Comment: If it’s still using a spinning hard drive, it probably died.  Did you try running Apple Diagnostics (hold `D` while booting).?

Comment: Hey Allan, thanks a lot for your response, I just tested the Apple Diagnostics and it cannot complete the test, not even the fastest one. I'm using an SSD. Something I did notice in the Diagnostics Hardware profile tab was that the power details show a voltage of 0 and a capacity of 0% not sure if this might have anything to do, maybe the battery is causing the problem?

Comment: It could.  If your battery is dead, it could be acting like a power "sink" and causing all sorts of issues.  It's very similar to having a car battery so dead that even hooking up another car via jumpers can't get it going and actually starts to pull power from the good car.